# Topview Controller for UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a table view that displays the parent folder details. When I select a row I want it to display contents of the corresponding child folder which has two windows using a Tab Bar Controller - One to display a table of details and one to display a graph.

The issue is the code I have found at [topviewcontroller for uitabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504729/topviewcontroller-for-uitabbar) is not able to display contents at a selected index path but rather a fixed index of 0 or whatever number manually input. I may be wrong about this affecting the result of displaying, I am not sure.

My code works fine for displaying the correct content in the immediate window but the second window linked to the tab bar controller doesn't display anything at all. I have swapped the windows and the same issue - first window displays, second does not.

This is my prepare for segue code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFileDetails"]){

        UINavigationController * navigate = segue.destinationViewController;

        //create a reference to the index path
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        FileDetailsVC * fileDetails = (FileDetailsVC *)[navigate.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];

        //Create a reference to the parent folder that is being selected 
        ParentFile * selectedFile = (ParentFile*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //reference it to the the next view
        fileDetails.selectedFile = selectedFile;
    }

}
```

I have tried to use "indexPath" in the [navigate.viewControllers objectAtIndex: ]; and changed the objectAtIndex to objectAtIndexPath however it gives an error message of "Incompatible pointer to integer..." and "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectAtIndexPath'".

Hopefully it's nothing difficult to solve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue's destination controller is a UITabBarController rather than a UINavigationController. You didn't set any datasource for the view controller in the other tab, so you don't see anything.

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
ViewControllerForTabItem2 * controller = (ViewControllerForTabItem2 *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
controller.dataSource = selectedFile;
```

Comment: Great thanks. I thought it was something minor like that. Working fine now.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to pass the details from Tableview through tabbar through navigation to the view? I want to have the navigation controller there for another link but it's throwing error because it's not recognising the details.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to achieve the exact same result as this question, however, in one of the 2 views, I have embedded a Navigation Controller because it's not displaying correctly. It would also help with naming it different to the first vc in the tab bar among adding buttons.

Comment: Suppose you get the Navigation Controller named nav, then nav.topViewController is your View 1 controller. And you can set selectedFile to View 1 controller.

Comment: My initial table view is embedded in a Navigation Controller. When I select a row to view more details, it takes me to the tab bar view 1 I have selected. That has content that is being blocked by a seemingly floating navigation bar. By embedding the the tab view 1 in a navigation controller, it displays fine. So I am wondering if I can embed tab bar view 1 in a nav controller to correct the view?

Comment: if you want to hide the navigation bar, just do self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES. And you should not bring in another navigation controller in since you already have one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62952/discussion-between-the-rooster-and-carouselmin).